# Magento on DigitalOcean server

Tags: php, mysql, apache, magento, digital-ocean

I have a problem with Magento store running on Digital Ocean server.

This is my droplet configuration:

```
2GB Ram | 40GB SSD Disk | New York 2 | Ubuntu Ubuntu 12.04.3 x64
```

When I am using Magento store, it works normally, except when I try to create account or do a purchase.

Then it takes 2 minutes to complete purchase.

I downloaded the whole site locally (with db) and the order and create account takes only few seconds.

I tried with upgrading droplet to 4GB Ram, but still the same.

This is my php configuration:

```
max_execution_time  30
max_file_uploads    20  20
max_input_nesting_level 64
max_input_time  60
max_input_vars  1000    
memory_limit    512M
```

I am not sure how to proceed with debugging this. Can someone advice?

Update #2 (based on UPD from MageWorx):
Based on MageWorx(updated) suggestion, I ran mysqltunner on the server. These are the results:

```
[OK] Logged in using credentials from debian maintenance account.
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.5.38-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MRG_MYISAM 
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 25K (Tables: 28)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 36M (Tables: 1386)
[--] Data in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tables: 0B (Tables: 17)
[--] Data in MEMORY tables: 0B (Tables: 68)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 1387

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 49s (338 q [6.898 qps], 71 conn, TX: 181K, RX: 51K)
[--] Reads / Writes: 92% / 8%
[--] Total buffers: 832.0M global + 2.7M per thread (100 max threads)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 1.1G (54% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/338)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 2% (2/100)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 32.0M/178.0K
[!!] Query cache efficiency: 12.9% (30 cached / 233 selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 12 sorts)
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 25% (57 on disk / 222 total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 97% (2 created / 71 connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 25% (1K open / 6K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 1% (104/8K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (248 immediate / 248 locks)
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 512.0M/36.8M
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0
-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Enable the slow query log to troubleshoot bad queries
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_limit (> 4M, or use smaller result sets)
```

These are the results from apachebuddy:

```
Your server has 2002 MB of memory
The largest apache process is using 39.78 MB of memory
The smallest apache process is using 15.04 MB of memory
The average apache process is using 17.32 MB of memory
Going by the average Apache process, Apache can potentially use 433.00 MB RAM (21.63 % of available RAM)
Going by the largest Apache process, Apache can potentially use 994.50 MB RAM (49.68 % of available RAM)

Generating reports...
### GENERAL REPORT ###

Settings considered for this report:

    Your server's physical RAM:     2002MB
    Apache's MaxClients directive:      25
    Apache MPM Model:           prefork
    Largest Apache process (by memory): 39.78MB
[ OK ]  Your MaxClients setting is within an acceptable range.
    Max potential memory usage:         994.5 MB

    Percentage of RAM allocated to Apache   49.68 %
```

Answer (score 2):

I dare to assume that the issue is caused by the lack of mysql settings optimization. The point is that without optimizing mysql, you won't be able to improve website speed, as mysql won't be using 100% of server resources.

These are the basic settings for 2Gb droplet (/etc/mysql/my.cnf):

```
key_buffer=32M
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_limit=1M
query_cache_size=32M
table_cache=128
innodb_buffer_pool_size=256M
```

As these are the basic settings, you can use the app http://mysqltuner.com/ for further mysql optimization.

Comment: Hi MageWorx, thanks for response. I updated my question with MysqlTunner results. I saw there is 2 exclamation marks on this item: Total fragmented tables. Should I do something about that? And do you have a suggestion how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

UPD:

As I can see from the results you got with mysqltuner, you need to experiment with the following settings:

```
skip-networking
query_cache_limit = 4M
query_cache_size = 256M

thread_concurrency = 4
table_open_cache = 4096
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 512M
join_buffer_size = 1M
```

Also note that after changes are made to the my.cnf file, don't forget to restart mysql

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

After settings are applies, test your website for some time, and then launch mysqltuner to see the results.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update. I updated those settings, but still the same. I also added new result from mysqltunner. Should I do something about number of Total fragmented tables? Maybe that is what is causing it to be slow

Comment: As far as the mysql is concerned, you need to run the command "mysqlcheck -u username -p --auto-repair --check --optimize --all-databases" Also I advise you to increase max_input_vars for php setting to 5000

Comment: I did all those, but still the same results. I contacted digital ocean to get more info. I installed also apachebuddy and added results from it. Still same behaviour.

Comment: To answer this question, we need to get the following details: 

What do you use as a mail server? (SMTP or internal)? 
Do the emails sent from your work email reach recipients? 
Which version of Magento you are on?  
What is the number of products in your online store? 
What extensions you are using on your store?

Comment: This might be the answer. I have no idea how emails are set to work. I will look more into that today and accept that as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: The mail server is the solution! So I didn't do anything to set up mail server in the beginning and that is why it took 2 minutes to send an email. So, I just set up Postfix mail server and it works as a charm. Can you add email answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

I use that exact Digital Ocean configuration (in terms of RAM and SSD - mine are on Centos and with the default PHP.ini config) for various Magento development/staging sites, they work fine so I'd say your server config is not the issue.  It must be inefficient code in either a template or module.

I'd start profiling for it;

https://www.nublue.co.uk/blog/using-magento-profiler-to-speed-up-magento-performance/

I still use the AOE profiler module, it makes life easier I think;

https://github.com/fbrnc/Aoe_Profiler

I would also run n98-magerun to see if there are module conflicts;

https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun

Then if you still can't find it switch to the default theme and start disabling modules to see which one it is.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I checked the site code, so it is not code related, for sure. Since, I tried using the same code on shared hosting. There is probably an error in my mysql or php configuration that I created on the server.

Comment: I also checked fresh Magento installation on that server and it had the same results.

Comment: Ah, my bad I missed your point about pulling it down locally and it  being OK there. I'll leave this answer just for general debugging links then.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I voted your link, since it is useful for debugging for Magento. Thanks anyway.